# sql queries not working : asp.net form connected to database and inserting data

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

.aspx file code

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <div style="background-color:lightgray;font-family:'Comic Sans MS' ">
  <br />
    <h2 style="text-align:center;"> CONTACT <b><span style="color:red">L</span>EA<span style="color:darkgreen">P</span></b> DRIVING SCHOOL</h2>
        <br />
    <fieldset style="align-content:center; color:lightgray;text-align:center ">
      <br /> <br />  
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Name" ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" size="25"  >  </asp:TextBox> <%--<asp:RequiredFieldValidator
            ID="rfvName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter Name"
            ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="#FF3300"
            SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>       --%>                                                                                               <br /> <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="mobile number" ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label> <br />
          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" size="25" ForeColor="Black"></asp:TextBox>  <%-- <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
            ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter Number"
            ControlToValidate="TextBox2" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="#FF3300"
            SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>                              --%>                      <br /> <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Email" ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label> <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"  size="25" ></asp:TextBox>   <%--<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEmailId" runat="server"
            ControlToValidate="TextBox3" Display="Dynamic"
            ErrorMessage="Please enter Email Id" ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rgeEmailId" runat="server"
            ControlToValidate="TextBox3" Display="Dynamic"
            ErrorMessage="Please enter valid email id format" ForeColor="Red"
            SetFocusOnError="True"
            ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>    --%>                                                                      <br /> <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="City" ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label> <br />
         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" size="25" ></asp:TextBox>                <br /> <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Message" ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label> <br />
        <asp:TextBox id="TextArea1" TextMode="multiline" Columns="27" Rows="8" runat="server" />  <br /> <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" Font-Bold="true" BackColor="Green" Width="83px" height="37px" OnClick="Button1_Click" />    &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Reset"  Font-Bold="true" BackColor="red" Width="83px" height="37px"/>


        <br /> <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </fieldset>
<br />
        <br />
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

.css file code

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // string connstring=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["yourconnstringInWebConfig"].ConnectionString;
     //   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
       // SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
       // con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=ADMIN;Initial Catalog=contact;Integrated Security=True";

        string insertSQL="INSERT INTO dbo.contct("  ;
        insertSQL += "name,number,email,city,msg)";
        insertSQL += "VALUES ('";
        insertSQL += TextBox1.Text + "','";
        insertSQL += TextBox2.Text + "','";
        insertSQL += TextBox3.Text + "','";
        insertSQL += TextBox4.Text + "','";
        insertSQL += TextArea1.Text + "','";

       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ADMIN;Initial Catalog=contact;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertSQL,con);
        int added = 0;
      try  {
          con.Open();
          added = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          Label1.Text = added.ToString() + "successfuly your information is submitted thank you!!";
        }
      catch (Exception er)
      {
          Label1.Text = "error while inserting record";
          Label1.Text = er.Message;
      }

      finally
      {
          con.Close();
      }
    }



}``
```

these are two file code form and sql query to insert value into form when user submits button it should add value to the table i created in sql database but no data is going there no value is being submitted i have tried no. of times but its not working plz help me out in this

Comment: it shows no error but when i run page and enter valus in form fields and click submit button no value goes to database tables

Comment: does it show successful message ? TIP: Please cross check your table name and also run the `insertSQL` part in **SQL** first and check what is the result you are getting

Comment: record is inserting but not in correct way it inserting int value and then show suucess msg in all others it shows error msg

Comment: I am still not getting what exactly not working for you. You need to be more specific on what should be inserted in which column. also please show us the table structure and aspx page too to get an exact answer.

On a helpful note. As suggested by `Izzy` your code is open to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) which may cause serious issues.

Comment: when i insert value in form page it got inserted but successfull msg is only displayed when i enter numbers in all fields

Comment: Oh. So which field you don't want to insert value and get the data inserted.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yous insert query sytax was incorrect hence no data was inserting. You was missing the closing bracket `)` from `VALUES()`, Currently your query is vulnerab to sql injection. I have parameterized your query and made changes to your code to reflect this. It is also recommended to make use of the `using` block to close and dispose the connection correctly.

```
string myQuery = "INSERT INTO dbo.contct(name,number,email,city,msg) VALUES(@name, @number, @email, @city, @msg)";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection("YourConnectionString"))
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(myQuery, connection))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@number", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@city", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox4.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@msg", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextArea1.Text;

        connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
} //Connection closed and disposed autmatically here
```

Read up on Sql injection [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: thank u izzy this code is working but i also want that when record is enetered succsfuly then msg should be displayed in label that successfull and fields of form after successful submission should be cleared to enter 2nd value in this case value gots entered but the data in fields remains as it is

Comment: and it shows me expcetion that string or binary data being truncated even when i ran using my own i was getting the same thing why is this so?

Comment: Your exeption means you're trying to insert data into a column where it's `DataType` is not big enough to hold the data you're inserting. As for your success message it's simple, include it as you already are and in your finally you can clear the TextBox values and set them to an empty string

Comment: u mean i should use the try catch block as i have been using before in my code?? but that exception is not being handled and i eneter the correct data according to the datatype limit i defined :(

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close `VALUES()`

```
string insertSQL="INSERT INTO dbo.contct("  ;
    insertSQL += "name,number,email,city,msg)";
    insertSQL += "VALUES ('";
    insertSQL += TextBox1.Text + "','";
    insertSQL += TextBox2.Text + "','";
    insertSQL += TextBox3.Text + "','";
    insertSQL += TextBox4.Text + "','";
    insertSQL += TextArea1.Text + "')";
```

Comment: only this is the problem?

Comment: Well a syntax error in your code won't make it work. I guess this is the problem there. Try it and tell us if that solved the problem @sababukhari

Comment: Also I hope you didn't forget an 'a' in your 'contct' table (did you mean 'contact' ?)

Comment: @sababukhari OK. mark the answer as accepted and you better rename your table "contact" without missing the "a"...

Comment: Maybe you should mention to the op that the query is open to sql injection